# Using CASE statement in Oracle procedure not working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have written below `CASE` statement for my logic to work. But it's not working and giving me error as

> Error(224,122): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + < / > at else end in is mod remainder not rem when    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || member submultiset The symbol "end" was substituted for ")" to continue.

Below is my code:

```
V_AMTINMONTH := (CASE V_DATEVAR_VALUE WHEN 'START' THEN V_AMTINMONTH WHEN 'END' THEN (V_AMTINMONTH - V_NOOFDAYSINMONTH + 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
v_amtinmonth :=
  CASE
     WHEN v_datevar_value = 'START'
     THEN
        v_amtinmonth
     WHEN v_datevar_value = 'END'
     THEN
        v_amtinmonth - v_noofdaysinmonth + 1
  END;
```